# Why is there a leading 1 in the binary representation of DCPU-16 instructions

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, dcpu-16

I'm currently fiddling around with DCPU-16 assembler (see http://0x10c.com/doc/dcpu-16.txt and http://jazzychad.net/dcpu.html).

There is one thing I don't understand in the way the assembler instructions are transformed to hex/binary.

As an example, take an instruction like

```
SET B, 0x0002
```

which is supposed to set the value of register B to decimal 2 (or hex 0x0002 or binary 0b000010)

Instruction format for DCPU-16 is

```
bbbbbbaaaaaaoooo
```

thus, 4 bits for the opcode at the lower end, 6 bits for the first value, 6 bits for the second value.

When transforming the instruction by hand, this is how I would do it:

```
SET == 0x1    == 0b0001
  B == 0x01   == 0b000001
       0x0002 == 0b000010
```

ending up with the complete instruction being

```
0b0000100000010001 == 0x811
```

but the correct value for DCPU-16 is

```
0b1000100000010001 == 0x8811
```

that is, a leading 1 is added - why is that?

I'm totally new to assembler and any other kind of hardcore low level machine instruction stuff, so please bear with me if this is a very stupid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the specs,

```
Values: (6 bits)
    0x00-0x07: register (A, B, C, X, Y, Z, I or J, in that order)
    ...
    0x20-0x3f: literal value 0x00-0x1f (literal)
```

Thus, literals `0x00-0x1f` are specified by the instruction-values `0x20-0x3f` - that is, the most significant-bit (out of the 6) is set.  So the literal `0x02` would have the instruction-value `0x22`.

The instruction-value `0x02` refers to the C-register, so what you thought the assembled instruction should be, `0b0000100000010001 == 0x811`, would actually be the instruction `SET B, C`.

Comment: Oh, of course, I get it. The CPU would have no way to distinguish whether the register or the value is meant. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let's see if I fully grok it - using this offset, I can write the literal decimal values 0 to 31 into the bbbbbb bit block of an instruction - but if i want to put, say, decimal 40 into register a, that is `SET B, 0x0028`, then the instruction `bbbbbbaaaaaaoooo` would be oooo = `00001` for `SET`, aaaaaa = `000001` for `B`, bbbbbb = `011111` for "next word (literal)", and then `0000000000101000` (= 40) on the next word?

Answer (score 0):

The textual description you've linked to doesn't say anything about how instructions are assembled into executable code, but you can reverse engineer it from the Javascript on the emulator page you've linked to. It seems that there is an internal function called "pack" that creates the binary instructions. The pack function does this:

```
words[0] += value << (4 + operand * 6);
```

which is called iteratively for the parsed input. I'd recommend asking the vendor / inventor(s) about assembly documentation.